# Zoom image javascript

Tags: javascript, html, image, zooming

Can someone explain me how to do an hover zoom like the first example of this page http://www.elevateweb.co.uk/image-zoom/examples (not with code but conceptually)?

Answer (score 1):

Sure its works like this:

**HTML**

```
<img id="zoom_01" src="small/image1.png" data-zoom-image="large/image1.jpg"/>
```

Note the two images, the src, and the data-zoom-image. One is the smaller pic the other is the larger.

**JAVASCRIPT**

```
$("#zoom_01").elevateZoom();
- See more at: http://www.elevateweb.co.uk/image-zoom/examples#sthash.QKWe4Oou.dpuf
```

In the source code below you can see how the elevateZoom() function works. 
Its pretty long, but straighforeward. If you hover over the picture, the code creates a new image that is offset to the side, which is a zoom in of the location of your mouse. Pretty cool!

**Source Code:**
https://github.com/elevateweb/elevatezoom/blob/master/jquery.elevatezoom.js

Answer (score -1):

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <meta charset='utf-8'/>
    <title>jQuery elevateZoom Demo</title>
    <script src='jquery-1.8.3.min.js'></script>
    <script src='jquery.elevatezoom.js'></script>
</head>
<body>
<h1>Basic Zoom Example</h1>
<img id="zoom_01" src='images/small/image1.png' data-zoom-image="images/large/image1.jpg"/>

<br />
see more examples online <a href="http://www.elevateweb.co.uk/image-zoom/examples">http://www.elevateweb.co.uk/image-zoom/examples</a>
<script>
    $('#zoom_01').elevateZoom({
    zoomType: "inner",
cursor: "crosshair",
zoomWindowFadeIn: 500,
zoomWindowFadeOut: 750
   }); 
</script>
</body>
</html>
```

1. import jquery.js
2. import jquery.elevatezoom.js

Comment: This does nothing to answer the question that was asked

Comment: Thank You for answers.What i don't understand is the relationship between the dimensions of the zoomed image and the normal image.Why if i incrase the zoomed image's dimentions the zoom becomes imperfect?